# Replacing just the first occurence of a character in a line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a line with thousands of lines like this:

```
{"100K";"0.00001";"10";"0.01"]}
{"101K";"0.0001";"100";"0.1"]}
{"102K";"1";"1000";"1"]}
{"102K";"1";"1000";"1"]}
{"103K";"0.01";"10000";"10"]}
{"104K";"0.1";"100000";"100"]}
{"105K";"1";"1000000";"1000"]}
{"109K";"0.000001";"1";"1"]}
{"120K";"0.000012";"12";"12"]}
```

I want to replace the first occurrence of `;` in a line with `:[`

Making these lines equal to

```
{"100K":["0.00001";"10";"0.01"]}
{"101K":["0.0001";"100";"0.1"]}
{"102K":["1";"1000";"1"]}
{"102K":["1";"1000";"1"]}
{"103K":["0.01";"10000";"10"]}
{"104K":["0.1";"100000";"100"]}
{"105K":["1";"1000000";"1000"]}
{"109K":["0.000001";"1";"1"]}
{"120K":["0.000012";"12";"12"]}
```

how do I do that with sed or other unix command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed 's/;/:[/' file

{"100K":["0.00001";"10";"0.01"]}
{"101K":["0.0001";"100";"0.1"]}
{"102K":["1";"1000";"1"]}
{"102K":["1";"1000";"1"]}
{"103K":["0.01";"10000";"10"]}
{"104K":["0.1";"100000";"100"]}
{"105K":["1";"1000000";"1000"]}
{"109K":["0.000001";"1";"1"]}
{"120K":["0.000012";"12";"12"]}
```

Comment: if you add `-i`, you do it in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```sh
awk '{ sub(/;/, ":["); print; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below 2 commands also:

```
perl -pne "s/;/:[/" filename
sed 's/;/:[/1' filename
```

Output:

```
{"100K":["0.00001";"10";"0.01"]}
{"101K":["0.0001";"100";"0.1"]}
{"102K":["1";"1000";"1"]}
{"102K":["1";"1000";"1"]}
{"103K":["0.01";"10000";"10"]}
{"104K":["0.1";"100000";"100"]}
{"105K":["1";"1000000";"1000"]}
{"109K":["0.000001";"1";"1"]}
{"120K":["0.000012";"12";"12"]}
```